# Vaadin - How to limit component squishiness and overlap?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.2

Consider this example:

```
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;

public class MyClass extends Panel {

    TextField        myField  = new TextField();
    TextField        myField2 = new TextField();
    HorizontalLayout hLayout  = new HorizontalLayout();

    public MyClass() {
        super();
        applySettings();
    }

    private void applySettings() {

        myField.setCaption( "Field1" );
        myField.setWidth( 100, Unit.PERCENTAGE );

        myField2.setCaption( "Field2" );
        myField2.setWidth( 25, Unit.EM );

        hLayout.addComponents( myField, myField2 );
        hLayout.setExpandRatio( myField, 1 );
        hLayout.setWidth( 100, Unit.PERCENTAGE );
        hLayout.setSpacing( true );
        hLayout.setMargin( true );

        this.setContent( hLayout );
    }
}
```

When the browser window is contracted you will see that **Field2** really *squishes* **Field1** (captions overlapping, in-fact, if Field2 width was even wider, it would squish Field1 completely making it vanish by ultimately overlapping it).

How may I apply a minimum width to a TextField to limit the squishing AND prevent the eventual overlap?

Comment: Did you try to set a minimum width via CSS on the field1?

Comment: Yes.  I created a styleName like this: `.v-panel-minwidth .v-panel { min-width: 700px; }` and called it like this: `this.setStyleName("minwidth")`.  I also played with `this.setWidth("700px")` -- nothing works.  My fields (as in the example above) sit within a `Panel` and I'd like to limit the width of the panel.

Comment: And in-case someone asks, I did this too: `.v-panel-minwidth .v-panel { min-width: 700px !important; }` -- still didn't work.

Comment: Since it's not working with the `Panel`, I thought I'd try it on my `ComboBox` component (on the real form I'm working on), so I did this `.v-filterselect-minwidth .v-filterselect { min-width: 10em !important; }` and called it like this `myCombo.setStyleName("minwidth");` -- still squishes into oblivion.

Comment: Just wondering, you put Field1 to 100%, which makes me think it's normal that there is no room left for Field2. Also if you set expandRatio to 1 for Field1, I believe there is no need to set a width for Field1 explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your example and played a bit with CSS. Looking at the HTML that Vaadin is generating, you have a structure like

```
<div style="v-horizontallayout ...">
 <div style="v-expand">
  <div style="v-slot">
    ...
      <input .../>
    ...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Setting **min-width** directly to the field did not work. However, putting the **min-width** CSS property on "v-slot" element worked for me, I tested with style:

```
.v-horizontallayout .v-slot {
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

To solve styling problems like this, I think it's handy to change styles inplace with Firefox built-in development tools or Firebug plugin until you have the desired effect and apply it to your CSS/SCSS file afterwards.

Comment: So in my case, since I need to limit the `Panel` width, this worked `.v-verticallayout-fixed .v-panel { min-width: 590px; }` and I called it like so `myLayout.setStyleName("fixed")`.  +1